# Golang: group and sum slice of structs

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, grouping, slice

I come from the .NET world where I had LINQ so I could do in-memory queries like the one we usually see in SQL.

I have a slice of this structure I want to group by 8 fields, and then sum another integer field. Something like:

```
type Register struct {
    id1 int
    id2 int
    id3 int
    id4 int
    id5 int
    id6 int
    id7 int
    id8 int
    money int
}
```

I thought in:

- Creating an Equal function, to compare structures (those eight
  fields).
  Iterate over the collection I'm analyzing.  For each item
  check if it is already in the hash table.  If it is there => I sum
  the field.  If it is not => I add the new item to hash table.

Is there a better way or any beautiful, efficient and easy ready to use
library?

Comment: I don't really follow your question. What is the purpose of an `Equal` function? I'm not sure if you're expecting a map of maps where all items with an id1 value `X` are in a group, all items with another id1 value `Y` are in a different group ect. Can you give an example of the input and output? Don't need a lot of data but enough to illustrate the point which your struct does not.

Comment: Yes, for example:

Comment: Yes, for example: `[r1{id1: 345, money: 1500}, r2{id1: 345, id2 140, money: 2700}, r3{id1: 345, money: 1000}`. So r1 and r3 should be summed and get `rSummed1{id: 345, money: 2500},  rSummed2{id1: 345, id2: 140, money: 2700}`. It is the classical `SELECT Sum(money) GROUP BY id1, id2 ...`

Comment: Wouldn't `r2` also be in that group? It's `id1` value is also 345.

Comment: No, because in r2 id2 != 0. All id fields need to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically your `idXX` fields are the keys, an n-tuple. And the `money` field is the data to be summed.

This can easily be done if you slightly refactor your types. Put only the keys into a struct, so it can be used as a key in a map. Struct values are [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

So the new types:

```
type Key struct {
    id1 int
    id2 int
    id3 int
    id4 int
    id5 int
    id6 int
    id7 int
    id8 int
}

type Register struct {
    key   Key
    money int
}
```

And to group and calculate sum, you can use a `map[Key]int`, using `Register.key` as the map key to "group" all registers with the same keys (same ids):

```
regs := []*Register{
    {Key{id1: 345}, 1500},
    {Key{id1: 345, id2: 140}, 2700},
    {Key{id1: 345, id2: 140}, 1300},
    {Key{id1: 345}, 1000},
    {Key{id3: 999}, 1000},
    {Key{id3: 999}, 2000},
}

// calculate sum:
m := map[Key]int{}
for _, v := range regs {
    m[v.key] += v.money
}

fmt.Println(m)
```

Output:

```
map[{345 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}:2500 {345 140 0 0 0 0 0 0}:4000 {0 0 999 0 0 0 0 0}:3000]
```

For a nice output:

```
fmt.Println("Nice output:")
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Printf("%+3v: %d\n", k, v)
}
```

Output:

```
Nice output:
{id1:345 id2:  0 id3:  0 id4:  0 id5:  0 id6:  0 id7:  0 id8:  0}: 2500
{id1:345 id2:140 id3:  0 id4:  0 id5:  0 id6:  0 id7:  0 id8:  0}: 4000
{id1:  0 id2:  0 id3:999 id4:  0 id5:  0 id6:  0 id7:  0 id8:  0}: 3000
```

This is as easy and as efficient as it can get. Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1p_625J5HE).

**Notes:**

In the map we didn't have to check if a `Key` is already in it. This is so because indexing a map yields the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the value type of the map if the key is not in the map. So in this case if a `Key` is not yet in the map, `m[key]` will give you `0` (`0` is the zero value for the `int` type), properly telling that the "previous" sum for that key is `0` so far.

Also note that `Key` may be an [embedded field](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) in `Register` instead of a "regular" field, it doesn't matter, and that way you could refer to the `idXX` fields as if they were part of the `Register`.

Comment: Awesome, this was the kind of thing I was looking for. I knew there was a much better way! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try go-linq: https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/go-linq/

It is similar to c# linq, use the GroupBy and Aggregate in your case

https://godoc.org/github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/go-linq#example-Query-GroupBy
https://godoc.org/github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/go-linq#example-Query-Aggregate

pseudo code:

```
From(regs).GroupBy(merge ids to a string as group key).Select(use Aggregate or SumInts to sum money)
```

Comment: Great! Seems exacty what I need! Thanks!