# Group by key + merge array values

Tags: go

I'm trying to merge the array values of multiple arrays with same keys (sort of group by + merge).  Is there any native way in Go to transform this input:

```
input = [
    [
        { a: 1, b: [1,2]},
        { a: 2, b: [1,2]},
        { a: 3, b: [1,2]}
    ],
    [
        { a: 1, b: [3,4]},
        { a: 2, b: [3,4]},
        { a: 3, b: [3,4]},
        { a: 4, b: [3,4]}
    ],
    [
        { a:1, b: [5,6]},
        { a:2, b: [5,6]},
        { a:3, b: [5,6]},
        { a:4, b: [5,6]},
        { a:5, b: [5,6]}
    ]
 ]
```

into:

```
output = [
    { a: 1, b: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
    { a: 2, b: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
    { a: 3, b: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
    { a: 4, b: [3,4, 5,6]},
    { a: 5, b: [5,6]},
]
```

Comment: I don't get the logic behind this? Do you calculate `a` value from the count of `b` indexes?

Comment: nope, i trying to merge all "b" values of the same "a" value.
so for a : 1 => [1,2] + [3,4] + [5,6] (b values from all the other arrays with the same "a" value)

Comment: See this related question: [Group and sum slice of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987023/golang-group-and-sum-slice-of-structs/39989962#39989962).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code isn't Go code (it would pass as Ruby), which, along with no clear attempt on your part to actually solve the problem, is probably why you got some downvotes and no answers yet.

One approach would be to interpret your code as Ruby would, with `input` a slice of slices of maps of (string, maybe, although Ruby would treat them as Symbols) keys to either ints (in the case of `a`) or slices of ints (in the case of `b`).  You could do that with the map values using the empty interface (`interface{}`), but it would be more straightforward to use a struct like this:

```
type ab struct {
    a int
    b []int
}
```

and have `input` be a `[][]ab`.  But as long as we're restructuring your data to fit the language better, it's even more straightforward to do away with `a` and `b` altogether, replacing that structure with a map where the `a` values are the keys and the `b` values are the values.  Things are then a simple matter of iterating over `input` and appending slices into `output`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    input := []map[int][]int{
        {
            1: []int{1, 2},
            2: []int{1, 2},
            3: []int{1, 2},
        },
        {
            1: []int{3, 4},
            2: []int{3, 4},
            3: []int{3, 4},
            4: []int{3, 4},
        },
        {
            1: []int{5, 6},
            2: []int{5, 6},
            3: []int{5, 6},
            4: []int{5, 6},
            5: []int{5, 6},
        },
    }

    output := make(map[int][]int)

    for _, m := range input {
        for k, v := range m {
            output[k] = append(output[k], v...)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

This produces the output:

```
map[1:[1 2 3 4 5 6] 2:[1 2 3 4 5 6] 3:[1 2 3 4 5 6] 4:[3 4 5 6] 5:[5 6]]
```

`output` thus has the data organized as you wanted, given the modified way of representing that data organization.

Comment: thank you @darshan-rivka-whittle for your response. Sorry my question was not clear enough, i was thinking about a json array input and a json array output.

Comment: What if a is actually an object of int and string , not just an int?